# docker private registry creation fails with following log msg: level=fatal msg="open /home/vignesh/certs/localregistry.crt: no such file or directory"

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am trying to create a private docker registry.
Following is the certificate directory and contents:

```sh
vignesh@vignesh-ThinkPad-E470:~/certs$ pwd
/home/vignesh/certs
vignesh@vignesh-ThinkPad-E470:~/certs$ ls -l
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 vignesh vignesh 4096 Jul 21 08:41 certs
-rwxrwxr-x 1 vignesh vignesh  920 Jul 21 08:41 localregistry.crt
-rwxrwxr-x 1 vignesh vignesh  712 Jul 21 08:41 localregistry.csr
-rwxrwxr-x 1 vignesh vignesh  963 Jul 21 08:41 localregistry.key
```

When I create the container it gets killed soon after create and status goes from "up" to "restarting"

```sh
docker run -d \
 --restart=always \
 --name registry3 \
 -v /home/vignesh/certs:/certs \
 -e REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:443 \
 -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/home/vignesh/certs/localregistry.crt \
 -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/home/vignesh/certs/localregistry.key \
 -p 443:443 \
 registry:2

vignesh@vignesh-ThinkPad-E470:~/certs$ docker container ls
 CONTAINER ID   IMAGE        COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                          PORTS                                             NAMES
 5e165c1c3b08   registry:2   "/entrypoint.sh /etc…"   18 seconds ago   Up 1 second                     0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, :::443->443/tcp, 5000/tcp   registry3
 vignesh@vignesh-ThinkPad-E470:~/certs$ docker container ls
 CONTAINER ID   IMAGE        COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                          PORTS     NAMES
 5e165c1c3b08   registry:2   "/entrypoint.sh /etc…"   19 seconds ago   Restarting (1) 2 seconds ago              registry3
 vignesh@vignesh-ThinkPad-E470:~/certs$
```

On checking the logs, I see following fatal error saying .crt file not found (several other non fatal messages also seen). But I am able to find the .crt file at path shown in message:

```sh
vignesh@vignesh-ThinkPad-E470:~/certs$ docker logs 5e165c1c3b08
time="2021-07-21T03:33:03.10806134Z" level=fatal msg="open /home/vignesh/certs/localregistry.crt: no such file or directory"

vignesh@vignesh-ThinkPad-E470:~/certs$ ls -l /home/vignesh/certs/localregistry.crt
-rwxrwxr-x 1 vignesh vignesh 920 Jul 21 08:41 /home/vignesh/certs/localregistry.crt
```

Could you please help me here.

Thanks,

Vignesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process inside the container sees files in the container's mount namespace, not your host. Since you mapped the directory to a different name in the container, you need to use that path:

```
docker run -d \
 --restart=always \
 --name registry3 \
 -v /home/vignesh/certs:/certs \
 -e REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:443 \
 -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/localregistry.crt \
 -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/localregistry.key \
 -p 443:443 \
 registry:2
```

Comment: I now see the following error --- level=fatal msg="tls: failed to parse private key". Could you please help us here

Comment: error message "failed to parse private key" was due to passphrase in the private key. Solved that issue by removing the passphrase. Now private registry is up.. Thanks for the help regarding certificate path :)